# How can I download Mavericks from Yosemite?

Tags: mac-appstore, install, macos

Does anyone know how to download Mavericks from Yosemite?  I'm trying to get the image to put on a different computer but it won't let me download it from the App Store.

I click "download" and it says "OS X 10.10 is already installed on this computer.  Are you sure you want to download OS X 10.9?".  I click "OK" and it does absolutely nothing.

[edit]

Solution for anyone looking for it: [How to re-download Lion from Mountain Lion](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/60933/how-to-re-download-lion-from-mountain-lion?rq=1)

Same thing works here.

- Open App Store
- Modify `/System/Library/CoreServices/SystemVersion.plist` and set `10.10` to `10.8`
- Start Download
- Revert modifications

Comment: Why can't you download 10.9 on the target machine directly?

Comment: Because the target machine is on dial-up.  I volunteer at a non-profit that's far enough away from everything that high-speed internet is impossible to get there.  Taking the machine away to update it isn't a viable option since they use it daily and I'm only there on weekends.  The issue is that they are starting to get warnings saying their current version of OSX is too old to run software.  So I just want to update the OS and feel like it shouldn't be this complicated to download it :)

Comment: The problem here is that questions involving not-yet-releases software (Yosemite in this case) are off-topic on Ask Different. Have a look at the related questions listed in the sidebar at the right, you might find ways to solve your problem there.

Comment: @patrix -- That's an extremely opinionated and pointless reason to list something as off-topic

Comment: I understand your situation but there are several reasons why we consider questions involving 10.10 off-topic currently (see http://meta.apple.stackexchange.com/questions/1712/are-ios-8-and-os-x-yosemite-questions-ok?cb=1 for details).

Comment: @patrix -- This question has nothing to do with Yosemite, it just happens to be what I'm using, and so it is perfectly on-topic.  "How do I download 10.9 from 10.10" is off topic, but "How do I download 10.8 from 10.9" is on topic?  That is an absurd distinction. I'm not discussing beta features, or anything specific to Yosemite. The question you linked to even leaves it open to interpretation and simply closing a question because it has the word "Beta", or in this case "Yosemite" in it isn't right. http://meta.apple.stackexchange.com/questions/1331/can-i-ask-about-not-yet-publicly-released-os

Comment: Let me backstep here a bit, as we explicitly seem to have thought about leaving "how do I get back from a beta to the latest public release" in scope. I've reopened the question, can you please move your answer text into an answer of its own (and accept it)? Sorry for the initial close.

Comment: I disagree with the re-opening. It's about using 10.10 app store which is beta and perhaps isn't made for re-downloading the main OS. The trivial way to download is to erase the Yosemite OS and all data and boot to internet recovery where you will get an older OS downloaded. It's in the FAQ and covered in several places on the site already. I'll find one and close this as dupe...

Comment: @bmike -- booting into recovery re-downloads Yosemite, and the question wasn't "How do I restore to Mavericks", it was "How do I download Mavericks".  If you're going to attempt to find a dupe, find one that is actually a dupe, not an incorrect tangent.  The answer you marked as "dupe" is ___not at all the same thing___

Comment: Booting to recovery on mavericks (which is on topic) downloads 10.9 or lower. The dupe I linked to has apple's own instructions to perform an erase install. If they don't work, you should open a support ticket with them. I've heard of no issues with people going back to mavericks from Yosemite, so perhaps your aren't following the instructions?

Comment: @bmike -- You're missing the entire point of the question.  This isn't about _restoring_ to Mavericks, it's about _downloading_ it.  Why are you ignoring that?!?  I even added a solution, why are you insisting that the question is about what you want it to be about instead of what I'm telling you it's about?

Comment: Please take this up on [meta] - questions about running 10.10 apps are off topic. I'll change the close reason.

Comment: @bmike -- This isn't about "10.10 apps", it's about downloading 10.9.  Just having "10.10" in the question ___does not make it off-topic___.  This was the entire point of my argument with patrix.  _specific_ questions about 10.10 are off-topic, ___not all of them___.

Comment: @bmike -- It's not an "opinion", it's following the guidelines.  You seem to like making your own guidelines without reference, so your "opinion" is the invalid one.

Comment: @bmike -- Care to point out exactly what guideline this question violates?  It doesn't discuss anything specific to 10.10, it doesn't discuss anything covered by the NDA, etc, etc.  This is clearly a case of blanket closing anything that says "10.10" without actually giving any logical thought to the context of the question.  Good job!  And I'm a mod on about 20 other SE sites, I just sincerely dislike mods that power-trip for no reason.

Comment: Please take this up on [meta] so several people can see the discussion. With 30k rep on SO can I presume you understand moderation and meta?

Comment: Yosemite OS X is now public beta, so above is moot. Also, great tip, thank you!

Comment: @Rudi the public beta still has the same NDA etc - so anyone who knows the answer faces the possibility of Apple banning them from future NDAs as they can't trust them and no professional is going to do that

Comment: Congrats Apple, for making things once again horribly complicated, useless, breaking, annoying and forcing people to hack the system to get simple things done.