# How can I download a newer Yosemite installer?

Tags: macos, mac-appstore

I have an existing Yosemite installer app from the original release of 10.10 (e.g. `Install OS X Yosemite.app`) but can't seem to download a newer installer.  When I click Download, I'm presented with this dialog:

[image: Mac App Store window showing OS X Yosemite and dialog reading "OS X v10.10.3 is already installed on this computer. Use the Updates page to install the 10.10 update or if you would like to download the OS X installer click Continue."]

However, clicking Continue doesn't appear to do anything.  No update appears to be in progress, no network activity shows in Activity Monitor.

The same dialog appears if I click the Download button in Purchases, and the download never begins.

How can I get an updated installer?

Comment: Could it be you already have the Installer? if yes move it to another location and try again.

Comment: In that screen it is a very faint information, it would change the Download to Downloading, and a small spinning circle top left. No further information that it is actually downloading. There would be also a progress bar in the Finder window / Applications.

Comment: If you have a copy of the Install OS X Yosemite.app bundle anywhere on your computer it will get updated/overwritten if you click Continue.  I moved the Install OS X Yosemite.app bundle that was for 10.10.0 from /Applications to /Temp and downloaded 10.10.2.  It did not create an Install OS X Yosemite.app bundle in /Application as it normally would and I did not  realize it until it was done and couldn't find it.  That is until I saw that the 10.10.0 one in /Temp had been updated.  I was irked as that was my only copy of 10.10.0.  I like keep a copy of each installer but oh well, that's life.

Comment: @user3439894 - the trick is to move it to another partition, then the system can't 'follow' it.

Comment: @Buscar웃: I do have a copy of the original 10.10 installer in my home directory, nothing in `/Applications` though.  It's definitely not updating the copy I have in my home directory.  The spinner doesn't appear to signify anything—it disappears when I click another tab in the MAS app and every time I go to Purchases, OS X Yosemite reverts to the Download button.

Comment: I just tried and successfully downloaded 2 copies (moved the first one out of the Applications folder). It takes me 30 minutes to download. And exited the Installer.

Comment: @Buscar웃: yeah, I've done it before myself with Mavericks.  Don't know what's going on here.

Comment: maybe this would work ? http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/60934/46541

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem appears to have been my copy of the installer that I had stashed away in a folder in my home directory, even though I'd originally made it by keeping a copy of the installer in `/Applications` (it was even owned by my user account instead of `root`!).

Once I removed that installer, the Mac App Store was happy to start the download for a new one.

Comment: Ahaah! Yes, unless you move it to another drive, or zip it & trash the original, etc,, the system will keep track of it.

Comment: A note on the file being on another drive - mine was on another drive. I ejected the drive, restarted the AppStore and could then download it again.

Answer (score 2):

I've seen this happen to a few people - it seems that the system is thinking in doublespeak - believing 2 things at the same time; that you need 10.10.3 but that you already have 10.10.3

Most times, this is resolved by downloading & installing the 10.10.3 combo updater, directly from Apple's Knowledge Base - https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1804

This will make sure you have all updated components since 10.10.0

Comment: Didn't work, unfortunately.  Still same problem.

Comment: Then I'm not sure what the problem is… what are you actually trying to achieve? A standalone full installer? You would do that from Purchases.

Comment: Also doesn't work.  I get the same dialog, it switches to a grayed "DOWNLOAD" button, but never actually starts downloading. I have done it both ways before…

Comment: I still don't know what exactly you're trying to achieve, nor exactly what you've tried. You really need to explain more.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't aware the question was unclear.  I have solved the issue since, but I'll update.